# QMD and R - Object not found when rendering

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

(**Newb to R**)

Writing a Qmd file for a report for a small project (partly to learn R for future projects)

Running each chunk whilst is editor works fine

```
source("MyGraphFile", local = knitr::knit_global())
```

```
mycommand_fromgraphfile
#generating a simple histogram
```

The code from the Graphs R file "MyGraphFile":

```
mycommand_fromgraphfile <-
  ggplot(mydata, aes(agey))+
  geom_histogram(color = 'white',
                 fill = scico::scico(1, begin = .3, palette = "berlin"),
                 bins = 20) +
  labs(x = "Age", 
       y = "Count") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = scales::pretty_breaks()
  )
```

When I go to render this as html, pdf etc. I get this error when it runs the first chunk above with source("MyGraphFile....

```
Quitting from lines 29-32 (report.qmd) 
Error in ggplot(mydata, aes(ageyears)) : 
  object 'mydata' not found
Calls: .main ... eval -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> ggplot
```

As I say, when running each chunk sequentially from the source/visual editor all works fine
I only get the above error when rendering the file

I've also tried simply running the whole ggplot command from within the qmd file, and not sourcing back to the graph R file, same error.

It seems the qmd file can't see the datafile when rendering? I've tested it with some of the example datasets and it renders fine, so clearly something I've missed. I've tried saving the datafile from previous cleaning and loading at the beginning of the qmd file, no luck

Any help for a n00b?

Comment: Is it a Quarto project or just a single qmd file? How are you currently saving and loading your `mydata` dataset and how was it built / loaded before? If you are using RStudio, by default it's using .RData file to save your workspace on exit and automatically loads it during startup, creating the illusion that all your objects survive session restarts. It makes somewhat convenient to continue where you stopped last time but you get hit by it as soon as you start to depend on it and/or start using something that first starts a clean session, like Quarto render / knitr knit.

Comment: Thanks @margusl .  That cleared it up for me.  As I suspected it's my lack of understanding of the R environment that's the problem.  Confession  - I wasn't saving the dataset!  Just loading that .RData file each time and/or re-running code.  Saving the dataset/loading it has solved my problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered

The Quarto render needs the dataset loading